# Listview inside stack widget is not working ( scrollDirection: Axis.vertical)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to make this design

[image]

This is my code result

[image]

But when i add listview it is not working 
I need vertical listing not horizontal

    ListView.builder(
                       scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                       shrinkWrap: true,
                       itemCount: 12,
                       itemBuilder: (context,index){
                         return Text("my widget card will add here");
                       })

This is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 

class MyAppNameAppTemplesListing extends StatefulWidget {
  MyAppNameAppTemplesListing({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppNameAppTemplesListingState createState() =>
      _MyAppNameAppTemplesListingState();
}

class _MyAppNameAppTemplesListingState
    extends State<MyAppNameAppTemplesListing> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.4,
        ),
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.14,
          color: Colors.pink[100],
        ),
       Positioned(
         child:  Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           child: Text("Temples",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         ),
       ),
        Positioned(
          top: 55,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4,right: 4),
            child:

            Column(

              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

              children: <Widget>[
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 50.0,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.97,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: new Container(
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                  bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                  bottomRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                  topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0))),
                          child: new Center(
                            child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.4),
                                child: new Text("Favourite",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
                          )),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 50.0,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.5,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: new Container(

                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                // Where the linear gradient begins and ends
                                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                // Add one stop for each color. Stops should increase from 0 to 1
                                stops: [0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9],
                                colors: [
                                  // Colors are easy thanks to Flutter's Colors class.
                                  Colors.pink[800],
                                  Colors.pink[700],
                                  Colors.red[600],
                                  Colors.red[400],
                                ],
                              ),
                              color: Colors.redAccent[100],
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                  bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                  bottomRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                  topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0))),
                          child: new Center(
                            child: new Text("ALL",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                          )),
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
               ListView.builder(
                   scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                   shrinkWrap: true,
                   itemCount: 2,
                   itemBuilder: (context,index){
                     return Text("my widget card will add here");
                   })

              ],
            ),

          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to wrap your `ListView.builder` in an `Positioned` widget and give it all the parameters.

Example:

```
Positioned(
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: ListView(),
        ),
```

This will take full size of the `Stack` parent.

**UPDATE:**

You can also use `Positioned.fill()` which will do the same thing.

Comment: This worked for me as well

Comment: @ArmandoSudi Great to hear that!

Answer (score 3):

you must wrap listview inside a container or sizedbox..

```
Container(
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: 2,
    itemBuilder: (context,index){
       return Text("my widget card will add here");
   }),
),
```

if the list still no appear, try give `height` and `width` on container.

Comment: ══════ (11) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#dee4e relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1695 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///Users/apple/Documents/namApp/devaayanam_app_temples_listing.dart:36:13
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 13 of 632 libraries in 2,395ms.

Comment: i need in vertical not horizontal

Comment: ════════ (11) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#89d48 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1695 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a fixed height to a horizontally scrollable widget. 
Please try wrapping your listview with a container or sized box with defined height.

```
 Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.3,
  // height: 50,
      child: ListView.builder(
                 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                 shrinkWrap: true,
                 itemCount: 12,
                 itemBuilder: (context,index){
                   return Text("my widget card will add here");
                 }),
)
```

Comment: ════════ (11) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#89d48 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1695 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: If you need vertical just add width to the container instead of the height in above code.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, you really need to optimize your widgets. You could have
>   achieved the design in a much easier way.

Now, you have made a little mistake with your current widget design pattern. You need to wrap your `Stack()` under `Column()` and move `ListView()` from `Stack()` and make it as second child of `Column()` and it should work.

**Full source code:**

```
Column(children: <Widget>[
          Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .4,
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .14,
              color: Colors.pink[100],
            ),
            Positioned(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Temples",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 95,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4, right: 4),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 50.0,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .97,
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: new Container(
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                                      topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                      bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                      bottomRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                      topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0))),
                              child: new Center(
                                child: Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                                .4),
                                    child: new Text(
                                      "Favourite",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    )),
                              )),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 50.0,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .5,
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: new Container(
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    // Where the linear gradient begins and ends
                                    begin: Alignment.topRight,
                                    end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                    // Add one stop for each color. Stops should increase from 0 to 1
                                    stops: [0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9],
                                    colors: [
                                      // Colors are easy thanks to Flutter's Colors class.
                                      Colors.pink[800],
                                      Colors.pink[700],
                                      Colors.red[600],
                                      Colors.red[400],
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  color: Colors.redAccent[100],
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                                      topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                      bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                      bottomRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                      topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0))),
                              child: new Center(
                                child: new Text(
                                  "ALL",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                              )),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
          ListView.builder(
              primary: false,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text("my widget card will add here");
              })
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes wrap listview with container but also add width and margin: EdgeInsects.only(left: 10.0) before widget you are calling image and image description data.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same issue when scroll direction was set to horizontal then was facing issue ,

i have solved it by by setting container width and height of listview parent widget, now working fine

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap `Listview.builder` into `Container` and set the height.
- In your `Listview.builder` set property `physics: BouncingScrollPhysics()`

  ```
  SizedBox(
    height: 350,
    child: ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return _card(index);
      },
    ),
  )
  ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Yes, I'm also the one faced the issue!
Use `Expanded()` as a parent of every child of `Stack()`.