# What is the best way to lay custom made bottom nav bar over the pages in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have background blurring bottom nav bar, and I want to overlay it on top of my pages(screens). If I keep it in `bottomNavigationBar:` the screen area gets reduced and I cant find a way to implement to have scrolling feature on my screens.

I have come with a 'not so pretty' way to do so.
my code:

```
            ...
              //scaffold body
              body: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  width: size.width,
                  height: size.height,
                ), 
                screens[...],

                // 2nd stack
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,

                      // from here bottom nav bar code
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: size.width,
                            height: size.height / 10,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    child: BackdropFilter(
                                      filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                                          sigmaX: 15, sigmaY: 15),
                                      child: Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Theme.of(context).brightness ==
                                                  Brightness.light
                                              ? const Color.fromRGBO(
                                                  184, 99, 99, 0.28)
                                              : const Color.fromRGBO(
                                                  255, 255, 255, 0.05),
                                          border: Border(
                                            top: BorderSide(
                                              width: 1,
                                              color: Theme.of(context)
                                                          .brightness !=
                                                      Brightness.light
                                                  ? Colors.white
                                                      .withOpacity(0.2)
                                                  : Colors.pink
                                                      .withOpacity(0.2),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

### Can anyone help me with a neater way, so that I get that glass blur effect on my nav bar?

and also about the scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **'glass blur'** effect, I'd go with the [glassmorphism](https://pub.dev/packages/glassmorphism) package. Although it will probably be a bit tricky to apply it to a bottom nav bar, this is likely your best bet.

The scrolling issue is *likely* due to your use of a `ListView` / `CustomScrollView` widget inside of the Stack. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69913343/19431523). **You must place the scroll view in a `Positioned.fill()` widget.**

Or, you can refactor your use of the bottom nav bar, place it in the `Scaffold`, & then remove the stack(s) entirely.